# catch ex.innerexception in the smtpclass vb.net2008

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, exception, smtpclient

am trying to catch the inner exception for the smtpclass with this code below, but it give another error saying the innerexception is not defined

```
Try
    mail.To.Add(lstRecipients(i))

    Try
        SetStatus("Sending:-" & lstRecipients(i))
        smtp.Send(mail)
        lSent += 1
        bwrkMain.ReportProgress(i + 1)
        SetStatus("Sent:-" & lstRecipients(i))
        lSent += 1
    Catch ex As SmtpFailedRecipientsException
        bwrkMain.ReportProgress(i + 1)
        SetStatus("Error:-" & lstRecipients(i) & " - " &
            ex.InnerException.Message)
    End Try
Catch ex As Exception
    SetStatus("Error:-" & lstRecipients(i) & " - " & ex.Message)
End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to check that your InnerException is not Nothing before trying to use it:

```
If Not(ex.InnerException Is Nothing) Then
     SetStatus("Error:-" & lstRecipients(i) & " - " &
            ex.InnerException.Message)
End If
```

Comment: wehn i send mail i get error `failure sending mail`. is it possible to get the actual reason why the mail was not sent, as in maybe network error, or smtp server error, or ivalid smtp password auth etc

Comment: @Smith I'm not sure how to get more information about why the email was sent. Good opportunity to post another question though.

Answer (score 2):

The InnerException is not defined, have a look at the [Exceptions within Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188914.aspx) section